# who is the default size of android tabhost height?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-tabhost

who is the default size (height) of an android tabhost ?
i have some problem to recognize the android tabhost heigt

*tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height =
                70;*

i try this for set to 70 the height but who is the default value ?

thanks a lot
by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the default value for your phone by following way:

```
double height = tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height;
```

Comment: each phone have a different tabhost height ?

Comment: Yes. It will be based on screen density and resolution.